# Align "Write-Host" with variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here it's my code :

```
Write-Host "Field 1 : " $variable1  
Write-Host "Field 2 : " $variable2
Write-Host "Field 3 : " $variable3
Write-Host "Field 4 : " $variable4
```

I get an output like :

```
   Field 1    : " $variable1    
   Field 2          : " $variable2
   Field 3      : " $variable3
   Field 4           : " $variable4
```

How can I align them?

Thanks

Comment: They should be aligned by default. The output will most likely not contain a double quote and variables will be replaced with their respective values. Can you confirm? It may help if you tell what is stored in the above variables, could be about special characters.

Comment: There is no way I know that input can produce that output. Please provide a test-case that is *reproducible*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, based on his previous questions that field1,2,3 ... are db fields names with variable length.

first solution, not very elegant but you can use the -f format operator to add some extra white-spaces to align your second column (bellow we use 40 characters minus the length of first column)

```
$field1=@("name";"username1")
$field2=@("age";24)
$field3=@("email";"you@there.com")

wh $field1[0] " : " $field1[1] 
wh $field2[0] " : " $field2[1]
wh $field3[0] " : " $field3[1]

wh

#fill some extra whitespaces 
$spaces1=40 - $field1[0].Length
$spaces2=40 - $field2[0].Length
$spaces3=40 - $field3[0].Length
"{0}{1,$spaces1}" -f $field1[0], " : "+$field1[1]
"{0}{1,$spaces2}" -f $field2[0], " : "+$field2[1]
"{0}{1,$spaces3}" -f $field3[0], " : "+$field3[1]
```

result

```
name  :  username1
age  :  24
email  :  you@there.com

name                                  : username1
age                                   : 24
email                                 : you@there.com
```

Second solution

If you create pscustom objects, then you can use all those fancy cmdlets such as format-table :) :

```
$col=@(
[PSCustomObject]@{$field1[0]=$field1[1]},
[PSCustomObject]@{$field2[0]=$field2[1]},
[PSCustomObject]@{$field3[0]=$field3[1]}
)

$col |ft
```

Result :

```
Name                           Value                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                 
name                           username1                                                                             
age                            24                                                                                    
email                          you@there.com
```